# Visual Studio member list window size (width) varies and is too small

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

Recently I found that the member list window in VS 2008 (open it by CTRL+Space or CTRL+J) has a different width, depending on which member variable I open it. See screenshot. I am sure that this behaviour has come a few days ago. It worked correctly before.

This is very annoying as I have to use the mouse quite often and drag it larger so that I can fully see the member names.
When I change the height, VS remembers it, but the width is forgotten and seems to be chosen randomly.

Has anyone else noticed that behaviour? How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what went wrong in VS, but it was project-dependent. The failure did not occur in other projects.
**I closed VS and deleted the solution's .ncb and .suo. Afterwards it was repaired.**
seems like deleting temporary files is always a good option.